# How to count direct or indirect children in org or outline mode

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode

I want to count the number of children in a subtree in org-mode. I am able to count the number of recursive children with `(outline-next-heading)`:

```lisp
(defun outline-count-subheadings (&optional recursive)
  "Count the number of subheadings below the current heading."
  (interactive)
  (let ((sum 0)
        (end (save-excursion
               (ignore-errors
                 (outline-end-of-subtree)
                 (point)))))
    (when end
      (save-excursion 
    (outline-next-heading)
    (setf sum 1)
        (while
        (< (point) end)
      (progn
        ;; todo: add conditional for recursive argument
        (outline-next-heading)
        ;;(org-forward-heading-same-level 1 nil) ; this does not terminate
        ;;(outline-forward-same-level 1) ; this errors with "No following same-level heading"
        (setf sum (1+ sum))))))
    (message (concat "Number of subheadings (" (if recursive "descendants" "direct children") "): " (format "%d" sum)))))
```

But for direct children `(org-forward-heading-same-level 1 nil)` does not terminate the loop and `(outline-forward-same-level 1)` errors with `No following same-level heading`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What you tried

`outline-forward-same-level` when called indefinitely will stop at the last direct child of the containing parent heading (and it will signal an error; `org-forward-heading-same-level` will stop at the same place, but it will *not* signal an error). Specifically, it will stop at the *beginning of the line* of the heading that represents the last direct child. `org-end-of-subree` will return the last point of the subtree, meaning the point at the *end of the contents* of the last direct child or, if the child has no contents, the point at the *end of the line* of the last direct child. This means that whether the last direct child has contents or not, repeated calls to `outline-forward-same-level` will necessarily end *before* the point returned by `org-end-of-subtree`. Keeping this in mind, we can see that your condition `(< (point) end)` will never return false. The reason you're getting two results is that both `outline-forward-same-level` and `org-forward-same-level` will not move point past the end of the subtree, which you need to do to fulfill your condition.

Another way of saying this is that both `outline-forward-same-level` and
`org-forward-heading-same-level` will always stop before the end of the subtree, so your loop won't end. Your recursive version works because `outline-next-heading` does not stop, so there will be a point where it goes past the last heading.

## How to fix

To fix this you can is to just stop the loop when you get an error from `outline-forward-same-level`. Alternatively, you can check if point hasn't moved which would involve keeping track of the last point in a variable. I will demonstrate the former because it is the most brainless and straight-forward way.

```
(defun outline-count-direct-children ()
  "Return the number of direct children in the current heading.
Note that this function modifies match data."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((sum 0))
      (when (and (org-at-heading-p)
                 ;; Make sure we go from parent to child. And indirectly
                 ;; ensure that we're not on the same heading (meaning that
                 ;; there are no more headings after this one).
                 (< (org-outline-level)
                    (progn (outline-next-heading)
                           (org-outline-level))))
        (setf sum 1)
        (while (condition-case nil (progn (outline-forward-same-level 1) t) (error nil))
          (setf sum (1+ sum))))
      sum)))
```

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Yes, very good answer. The commands are obviously working well in that they don't move point to a heading at a higher level, and I missed that. Your `org-outline-level` pointed me in a direction of using the same logic for direct children and descendants, and I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Aquaactress's great answer, here is a function inspired by that solution, along with some logic that calculates both the number of direct children and overall descendants:

```lisp
(defun org-count-subheadings ()
  "Count the number of direct and recursive subheadings below the current heading."
  (interactive)
  (let ((descendants 0)
        (children 0)
        (heading-level (1+ (org-outline-level)))
        (end (save-excursion
               (ignore-errors
                 (outline-end-of-subtree)
                 (point)))))
    (when end
      (save-excursion 
        (while (and (outline-next-heading)
                    (< (point) end))
      (progn
        (setf descendants (1+ descendants))
        (when (= heading-level (org-outline-level))
          (setf children (1+ children)))))))
    (message "%d direct children, %d descendants" children descendants)))
```